# Is it possible to dynamically change the value of html form's action tag value with one of its fields?

Tags: javascript, html

I searched a lot(S.O & GOOGLE) but was not able to find any closer looking approach to solve my problem.

I have a simple html5 form having 9-10 inputs and uses "mailto:abc@xyz.com" tag to compose an email having all the entered data through inputs in there.
Upto here i'm fine but now i need to change the "abc@xyz.com" value with one of its input field.

e.g.

```
 <form method="post" action="now it should have what is value of 1." enctype="text/plain">

  1. <input type="Email" name="ToEmail" id="ToEmail" value="" required placeholder="Target Email Address.."/>
  2. 
  3.
   .
   .
  <button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
 </form>
```

What i tried myself:
created a javascript function
     function actionValue()

```
        {
        var email = document.getElementById('ToEmail').value;
        var action = "mailto:"+email+"?subject=Test"
        return action;
        }
```

and called this function like this

```
  <form method="post" action="javascript:actionValue();" enctype="text/plain">
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with my logic or the way i'm using the javascript.
Any help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks,
p.s : I'm not that good with js..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" onSubmit="this.action='mailto:'+document.getElementById('ToEmail').value;" enctype...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the inline stuff from your HTML:

```
(function() {
  var theForm = document.querySelector('form');
  theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    theForm.action = document.getElementById('ToEmail').value;
  });
}());
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/odihew/1