# Changing the recipient of the mailto to what is entered in the text field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailto

I wanted to know if it possible to make a form where one could change the email to which the mailto action is set, to what is entered in the text field.

for example:

```
<form enctype="text/plain" method="get" action="mailto:getElementByName='friend1'" action="cc:manager@crill.com">
Friend 1 <input type="text" name="friend1"><br>
Friend 2 <input type="text" name="friend2"><br>
Friend 3 <input type="text" name="friend3"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

So if in the first field named "Friend 1" I would enter: "example1@mail.com", then when I press submit I wanted it to take the info that was placed into the first field and make it the mailto.

I apologise for my english, hope whom ever reads this understands it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/15218012/786096

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867613/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-the-recipient-of-mailto-with-only-html-and-ja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" onSubmit="this.action='mailto:'+document.getElementById('friend1').value;" enctype...>
```

Check here too: [Is it possible to dynamically set the recipient of MAILTO: with only HTML and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867613/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-the-recipient-of-mailto-with-only-html-and-ja)